# Keyboard navigation of jump-lists in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, jumplist

As a keyboard-aholic, I used to call up the jumplists of my most-used applications with the keyboard and then start typing the entry I wanted to navigate to it.  I lost that ability with Windows 10 because typing to navigate doesn't work anymore.  Does anyone know a way to get that function back?

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Number</kbd>
to open the jump list for the app pinned to the taskbar in the
position indicated by the number.

Once the jump list is opened, the up-down arrow keys can navigate
inside and the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key launches the current entry.

Note that you need to use the number keys, not the ones that are
in the numeric pad.

Reference :
[Keyboard shortcuts in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec#WindowsVersion=Windows_10).

Comment: Right.  That's what I was doing in Wndows 7, and I would subsequently start typing the jumplist entry I wanted to select, but that functionality seems to have been taken away with Windows 10.

Comment: @agerber85: It's working for me on Windows 10. The post is labelled "windows-10" after all.

Comment: must be nice.  It hasn't been working for me since I upgraded.

Comment: Weird. Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Hmmm...I'm not sure I should be running those commands.  This is my work computer.  It belongs to the company, and we don't have a tech support team, here.  I'm not sure I want to explain that I made a mistake that crippled my system because I was trying to fix a convenience feature.

Comment: In that case, run only `sfc /verifyonly` as Administrator, which will only check.

Comment: "Windows Resource Protection found integrity violations."  There you have it.  What I can't figure is why this would have happened immediately after the upgrade to Win 10.

Comment: This might explain something. Normally I would advise at this point to [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html), but with a company computer it's you that needs to decide what to do. The simplest solution might be to rollback the upgrade - what was the Windows version before it?

Comment: It was Windows 7, and I know rolling back the upgrade is something I'm not permitted to do.

Comment: As SFC found integrity violations, your Windows version is not in perfect shape. You might consider, if you're permitted, to do [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). Mind your backups.